# How to fix the HTTP error 405 when trying to run connect.php using VS Code?

Tags: php, macos, visual-studio-code, xampp

I'm trying to create a registration form that stores all the new data entered by users into a database using XAMPP phpmyadmin, but every time I try to submit the form by clicking on the register button, it returns this error:

> This page isn't working. If the problem continues contact the site owner. HTTP error 405

I'm on a Mac btw.

This is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sign Up - Bloom of Psyche</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="register-form.css">

</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="formbox">
      <div class="form-value">
        <form method="post" action="connect.php">
          <h2>SIGN UP</h2>
          <div class="inputbox">
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="firstName" required>
            <label for="">First Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="inputbox">
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="lastName" required>
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="inputbox">
            <input type="email" id="email_address" name="email" required>
            <label for="">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="inputbox">
            <input type="password" id="user_password" name="password" required>
            <label for="">Password</label>
          </div>
          <button>Register</button>
          <div class="login">
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="login-form.html">Log in</a></p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```php
<?php
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bloomofpsyche_database');
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die('Connection Failed : '.$conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, email, password) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "You have successfully registered!";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: The built-in VS Code webserver can't run PHP code, or even accept POST requests. It's only useful for basic, static / frontend sites. You need to run your code on Apache. If you've installed that (via XAMPP, for example) then it should be available on `http://localhost`. You may need to configure it to point to where your PHP  files are located.

Comment: P.S. To make your code more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command.

Comment: And you should never be echoing error data deliberately (e.g. in your `die('Connection Failed : '.$conn->connect_error);` line) - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. Instead let PHP handle the error, and in a development environment it can show the error on screen, but in a live environment it should be configured to log it to a file instead.